# Got "javax.ejb.EJBException: error unmarshalling arguments java.io.EOFException" when calling an ejb method

Tags: java, serialization, ejb, weblogic, solaris

I am running an ejb method belongs to a EJB located in **weblogic 10.3.6** server. This server is located in a **Solaris-10 64bit** machine. EJB client is located in **Windows XP 32bit** machine.

When I am executing this ejb method (inside a junit test case), I get this strange exception. I googled several times thinking about different reasons, but I am still unable to find a solution for this.

I checked the source code of **java.io.DataInputStream** and this **java.io.DataInputStream.readInt()** method throws this exception if this input stream reaches the end before reading four bytes.

Does any of you have an idea about this issue? thanks in advance.

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException; nested exception is: java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:2775)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:949)
    at com.company.product.ClassDomain.readExternal(ClassDomain.java:356)
    at com.company.product.ClassDomainChild.readExternal(ClassDomainChild.java:129)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1791)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:208)
    at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.readObject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:599)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:204)
    at com.company.product.ProductFacadeSessionBeanWithAffinity_c8b15i_ProductFacadeSessionRemoteWithAffinityImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:667)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.invoke(ClusterableServerRef.java:230)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:518)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
javax.ejb.EJBException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException; nested exception is: java.io.EOFException
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:121)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:96)
    at $Proxy7.createApplicationInstance(Unknown Source)
    at tools.actions.InitTest_CreateDomain.performInit(InitTest_CreateDomain.java:94)
    at com.company.tools.TestUtils.registerInitAction(TestUtils.java:114)
    at com.company.tools.TestUtils.createDomain(TestUtils.java:607)
    at com.company.product.test.Provisioner.provisionProfiles(Provisioner.java:388)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:98)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:79)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:77)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:2775)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:949)
    at com.company.product.ClassDomain.readExternal(ClassDomain.java:356)
    at com.company.product.ClassDomainChild.readExternal(ClassDomainChild.java:129)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1791)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:208)
    at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.readObject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:599)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:204)
    at com.company.product.ProductFacadeSessionBeanWithAffinity_c8b15i_ProductFacadeSessionRemoteWithAffinityImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:667)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.invoke(ClusterableServerRef.java:230)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:518)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:
```

221)

Comment: May be it's an issue because of the separate architecture, did you try using a windows 64 bit machine run the EJB client? And there's no problem when you run both on a solaris 64bit machine?

Comment: May be. But I don't have a Windows 64 bit machine now to check that.

Comment: If the problem is due to the native data type differences in the bits then you don't really have a choice as far as I know than switching... Don't know if a VM will help though... May be you should try that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this problem was, my Eclipse IDE was using an old version of the api.jar file from its cache. :/

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem occur in a `readExternal` method, you have probably a matching `writeExternal` method.

You should check the `writeExternal` to see if you are writing the same amount of stuff than you are trying to read. It may lack a `writeInt()` call.

Comment: I checked the writeExternal method. It writes the same amount of data expected by readExternal method.